# $JAVA_HOME doesn't direct to latest java installation

Tags: java, linux

I have a CentOS 7 VM. I recently installed `1.8.0_251` jdk version. Previous jdk version was `1.8.0_172`. I inserted the following lines to a `custom.sh` script in `/etc/profile.d/` to affect the new java version system-wide.

```
export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_251-amd64/bin:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_251-amd64/"
```

I get the java version correctly.

```
[igwstuser@integrator1 ~]$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

Still I get the early version when `JAVA_HOME` is invoked through `igwstuser`. When `JAVA_HOME` is invoked through `root` user, I get the correct version. How can I resolve this?

```
[igwstuser@integrator1 ~]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_172-amd64/
[igwstuser@integrator1 ~]$ sudo su
[root@integrator1 igwstuser]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_251-amd64/
```

Comment: Did you make sure to log out and log in again after adding `custom.sh`? Have you checked `igwstuser`'s `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` for a line that overrides?

Comment: @thatotherguy: Yes, I logged out and logged in. Yes checked ```igwstuser```'s ```.bashrc``` and ```.bash_profile```.  No overriding lines

Comment: What are the permissions on /etc/profile.d/custom.sh?  Who can read it?

Comment: @jsbillings: You are a genius. I had not set read access to other users in `custom.sh`.
Thanks.

Comment: @jsbillings: Please post this as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions on /etc/profile.d/custom.sh need to be open so all users can read the file during login. Only root can read it if only root is getting the setting.

Answer (score 1):

- Did you check your bashrc as "igwstuser"?
- Is it pointing to the right java version?

Just do this and check which java version it is pointing to with `cat ~/.bashrc`

If you see some other java version then using text editor set correct value for `export JAVA_HOME=`

After making necessary changes don't forget to `source` bashrc to make changes available with `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: No JAVA_HOME set at ```~/.bashrc```. JAVA_HOME works fine for root user

Comment: just set JAVA_HOME in bashrc and source bashrc, it will work fine

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I want to understand where this old version is coming from

Comment: run `env` to show all your env variables, try to find out where did you set other JAVA_HOME

Comment: check this file - /etc/java/java.conf

It should have something like below line
# Root of all JVM installations
JVM_ROOT=/usr/lib/jvm


which will make it possible to identify all installed java versions. even "env" may show no results and echo $JAVA_HOME may return empty result, but still java will work fine (may be due to configuration in this file).

also I think "alternatives --config java" may pick up available java's from this config file. 

So I think your old version of java is coming somewhere from here

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/profile.d` is for global users, for Linux env, this file runs first, then ~/.bash_rc and ~/.bash_profile for individual users.
You need to check this user `integrator1`'s `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`, is there a JAVA_HOME set. If it is, change it to your latest JAVA_HOME. Then `source` it.

Comment: No JAVA_HOME set at ```igwstuser```'s ```.bashrc``` and ```.bash_profile```

Comment: you can try add the new `JAVA_HOME=="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_251-amd64/" ` into ~.bashrc, then source it. It should work.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I want to understand where this old version is coming from